# Indirection requires pointer operand

Tags: c++, file-io, outputstream, pointers

I'm getting this error, Indirection requires pointer operand ('int invalid') in this code, I think I'm using empPtr wrong in this code, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance guys.

I will also include my other classes at this link. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/08ff6c5284c179c9a323

My input text file looks like this.

```
123,John,Brown,125 Prarie Street,Staunton,IL,62088
124,Matt,Larson,126 Hudson Road,Edwardsville,IL,62025
125,Joe,Baratta,1542 Elizabeth Road,Highland,IL,62088
126,Kristin,Killebrew,123 Prewitt Drive,Alton,IL,62026
127,Tyrone,Meyer,street,999 Orchard Lane,Livingston,62088
```

Here is my main.cpp.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "Employee.h"

using namespace std;

bool openFileForReading(ifstream& fin, const string& filename);
bool openFileForWriting(ofstream& fout, const string& filename);

int readFromFile(ifstream& in, Employee empArray[]);

void writeToFile(ofstream& out, const Employee empArray[], const int numberofEmployees);

int main() {

    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;

    if(!openFileForReading(fin, "employeesIn.txt")) {
        cerr << "Error opening employeesIn.txt for reading." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    if(!openFileForWriting(fout, "employeesOut.txt")) {
        cerr << "Error opeing employeesOut.txt for writing." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    Employee employeeArray[50];

    int employeeCount = readFromFile(fin, employeeArray);

    fin.close();

    writeToFile(fout, employeeArray, employeeCount);

    fout.close();

    cout << "Program successful." << endl << endl;


    return 0;
}

bool openFileForReading(ifstream& fin, const string& filename) {
    fin.open("employeesIn.txt");

    return (fin.is_open());
}

bool openFileForWriting(ofstream& fout, const string& filename) {
    fout.open("employeesOut.txt");

    return (fout.is_open());
}

int readFromFile(ifstream& in, Employee empArray[]) {
    int temp = 0;
    string eidText;
    string first;
    string last;
    string street;
    string city;
    string state;
    string zipcode;

    while(!in.eof()) {
        getline(in, eidText, ',');
        getline(in, first, ',');
        getline(in, last, ',');
        getline(in, street, ',');
        getline(in, city, ',');
        getline(in, state, ',');
        getline(in, zipcode);

        empArray[temp].setEid(stoi(eidText));
        empArray[temp].setName(first, last);
        empArray[temp].setAddress(street, city, state, zipcode);

        temp++;
    }

    return temp;
}

void writeToFile(ofstream& out, const Employee empArray[], const int numberOfEmployees) {

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEmployees; i++){
        out << "Employee Record: " << empArray[i].getEid()
        << endl
        << "Name: " << empArray[i].getName()
        << endl
        << "Home Address: " << empArray[i].getAddress() 
        << endl
        << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: That was when I thought I had it correct :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
int empPtr = 0;
```

followed by

```
(*empPtr).setEid(stoi(eidText));
```

which is clearly the cause of this error.

Comment: What would you change int empPtr to? Also, what do you think about my array declarations?

Comment: First of all you are never using the value of `Employee empPtr = employeeArray[50];`, so I'm not sure what the purpose of that line is. Although though you are accessing an index past the end of the array (`[50]`), that is a run time error and would not cause a compiler error. Second of all `empPtr` is not a pointer, it is just a stack variable of type  `Employee`. I'm not sure what you are trying to do in `readFromFile`, but you cannot dereference a non pointer type, `int` in this case, which is what `empPtr` is in that method.

Comment: I didn't want to use empPtr in the first place, but was referred to it by someone else, I have changed the above code back to what I originally had before empPtr.  My output file opens, yet nothing is being written to it.

Comment: So are you still getting an error? I don't see `empPtr` at all anymore.

Comment: I have removed empPtr, looking for other options why my output to file is not working, it opens the file but isn't writing for some odd reason.

Comment: Are you sure `employeeArray` is being populated with anything and `employeeCount` is not 0?

Comment: Yes I believe it is, when I look at empArray in the debugger it looks like everything is being populated.  Maybe my temp is wrong? But I don't think that would have an effect.

Comment: It actually says this line is messed up I believe   empArray[temp].setEid(stoi(eidText));    in the debugger it says eidText is ""

Comment: Well there's your problem. All of your data is probably empty strings, so nothing is getting written to the file. `getline` is probably not working correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60734/discussion-between-matthewtingle-and-mclaassen).

Comment: I don't get it. can you access a variable as a variable some of the time and pointer other times, and if so how? would it change anything if I access it as a pointer all of the time?

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong.

```
Employee empPtr = employeeArray[50];
```

The maximum valid index for `employeeArray` is `49`.

To get the first item of the array, use:

```
Employee empPtr = employeeArray[0];
```

To get the last item of the array, use:

```
Employee empPtr = employeeArray[49];
```

More on accessing C and C++ arrays can be found at http://www.augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/arr.html and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm.

Comment: What should I change it to?

Comment: I've changed it to the [49] version, and I still get the error in my (*empPtr).setEid(stoi(eidText));

Comment: @MatthewTingle, as mclaassen correctly pointed out, that fixes a run time error not a compile time error. mclaassen's answer addresses the compile time error.

Comment: I have since removed empPtr from my code completely, we have not learned pointers yet, so I will not use them. My output file opens, but nothing is being written to it.

Comment: @MatthewTingle, I see your updated code. Are you seeing any more compiler errors?

Comment: Nope, no compiler errors, and it looks like my array is being populated.